# When will Ubuntu Touch be available for Xperia Tipo release

Tags: ubuntu-touch

When will Ubuntu Touch be available for Xperia Tipo release? I am aware that it does not have a 1 GHz Processor, but I have successfully overclocked it to over a GHZ.

Answer (score 0):

I guess never. The device is even overclocked not that powerful, although it's not that spreaded.